# Solr Index on Hive - Fails for more rows

Tags: hadoop, solr, hive, hdfs

I created a Solr Index on a Hive table with below steps. This worked for 25 rows which were accessible from the Solr Collection. But when I tried to load 1000 rows from the Hive Internal table to the Hive External table, it failed.
Pls help.

1) `CREATE TABLE ER_ENTITY1000(entityid INT,claimid_s INT,firstname_s STRING,lastname_s STRING,addrline1_s STRING, addrline2_s STRING, city_s STRING, state_S STRING, country_s STRING, zipcode_s STRING, dob_s STRING, ssn_s STRING, dl_num_s STRING, proflic_s STRING, policynum_s STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';`

2) `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/Solr1.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE ER_ENTITY1;`

3) `add jar /home/solr-hive-serde-3.0.0.jar;`

4)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE SOLR_ENTITY999(entityid INT,claimid_s INT,firstname_s STRING,lastname_s STRING,addrline1_s STRING, addrline2_s STRING, city_s STRING, state_S STRING, country_s STRING, zipcode_s STRING, dob_s STRING, ssn_s STRING, dl_num_s STRING, proflic_s STRING, policynum_s STRING) STORED BY 'com.lucidworks.hadoop.hive.LWStorageHandler'
    LOCATION '/user/SOLR_ENTITY1000' TBLPROPERTIES('solr.server.url' = 'http://URL/solr','solr.collection' = 'er_entity999','solr.query' = '*:*');
```

********** All above steps work fine **********

5) This step fails ...

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE SOLR_ENTITY999  SELECT * FROM ER_ENTITY1000;
```

... With error:

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE SOLR_ENTITY999  SELECT * FROM ER_ENTITY1000;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = i98779_20180308085142_3918b9ea-2158-4b0e-865f-2fcdefc17e4b
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2018-03-08 08:51:45,993 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_local1283927429_0001 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged under elasticsearch?

Comment: Removed <Elastic Search> tag.

Comment: Can you find the job logs for `job_local1283927429_0001` in YARN?

Comment: This is what the JOB LOGS say:

java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.